# Rally-Node REST API return specific User Story or Defects

Tags: node.js, rally

I'm reading the [rally-node wiki](https://github.com/RallyTools/rally-node/wiki/User-Guide) and I don't get how to **Read an Object**. The part I don't get is the `ref` part.

How would I know the `ref` of the user story if I only know the title and the formatted ID (US5) of the story?

I know that after creating a user story I have a `_ref` that contains `.../hierarchicalrequirement/121212121212` and by using that I can read the object, but is there another way of doing it? Since how would I know what my `_ref` is of a user story I created a long time ago?

Or is the best way to get user story from Rally is using `restApi.query({})`?

What I want to do is to return a specific user story, defect, etc from Rally with specific fetch data i.e. Formatted ID, Name, etc.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your instincts are correct- ff you only know the FormattedID or Name you'll need to just [query](https://github.com/RallyTools/rally-node/wiki/User-Guide#query-a-type) for it.

```
restApi.query({
    type: 'hierarchicalrequirement', //the type to query
    fetch: ['FormattedID', 'Name', 'ScheduleState', 'Children'], //the fields to retrieve
    query: queryUtils.where('FormattedID', '=', 'US5'), //formatted id filter
    scope: {
        workspace: '/workspace/1234' //specify to query entire workspace
    }
}).then(); //process results
```

Comment: A quick question, how would I use `restApi.del`? Same thing, how do I find out the `_ref` property in order to delete a user story?

Comment: It's the same.  WSAPI deals in refs (type + object id).  So if you don't know the ref you'll have to query for it first by name or formatted id...

Comment: I got it to work by query for the object then use  `_ref`from it to call `restApi.del`. I'm just wondering is there an easier way of doing this? Without having to first query for the refs. Thanks

Comment: currently not.  that would be a cool addition to wsapi though- to be able to address items by formatted id!